# recent update broke Kodi

Tags: upgrade, crash

As of July 3rd Kodi doesn't launch only a black screen then crash, see pastebin, http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/DhcsNcjkSK/

Previous kernel (4.15.52) will not launch either, but unupdated second incidence of Ubuntu 18.04 using 4.15.52 will launch. Suggestions on how yo repair greatly appreciated.

Comment: my suggestion : uninstalling and downloading kodi from their website and running the installer again.

Comment: How did you obtain Kodi 18.3, from kodi.tv web site? Did you uninstall earlier Kodi that may have been installed from the Ubuntu repos? Are your System Updates current? What is "unupdated second incidence of Ubuntu 18.04 using 4.15.52 will launch"?

Comment: I installed Kodi from yhe PPA: and update and upgrade regularly

Comment: sudo apt-get install software-properties-common
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:team-xbmc/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install kodi

Comment: I have a dual boot system with Bionic on both /dev/sda1 and /dev/sda6 (a fall back for Mythtv updates that may go awry) I've been using sda1 recently and not updating sda6 which will launch kodi but sda1 will not

Comment: sda1 is using kernel 4.15.54 with 4.15.52 as backup and sda6 is using kernel 4.15.52 with 4.15.50 as backup

Comment: I've un-installed and re-installed to no avail. Does the crash report give any clue to what should be repaired / downgraded?